# ElasticSearch "Match" with FullText Matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with ElasticSearch.
When I do this query:

```
{query: "blackberry -q10"}
```

I get exactly what I want (all results which have reference to BlackBerry but not Q10).

However, I want to restrict the fields which are searched to just the "title" field. Eg, the _source documents have titles, body, tags, etc. and I only want to search the title. The ElasticSearch "Match" seems right for me...

```
{query: {match: {title: "blackberry -q10"}}}
```

While this succeeds in only searching the title, it still returns results with have Q10 in the title, unlike the search above.

I'm looking at [the match documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html) but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Match query doesn't use negation syntax like that.  E.g you can't use a "minus" to negate a term.  It will be parsed as a hyphen by the default search analyzer.

I would use a filtered query in this case.  You could add the negation in a query...but a filter will be much faster.

```
{
  "filtered":{
     "query":{
        "match":{
           "title":"blackberry"
        }
     },
     "filter":{
        "bool":{
           "must_not":{
               "term":{
                  "title":"q10"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Note, you may need to change the `term` filter, depending on how you analyzed the field at index time.

EDIT:
Based on your comment below, if you really want to keep the ability to do negations "inline", you would use the `field` query (a more specific version of `query_string`, which would also work).  This query uses Lucene syntax, which allows inline negation

```
{
   "field" : {
       "title" : "blackberry -q10"
   }
}
```

The reason `query_string` and it's derivatives are not recommended is because it is easy to shoot yourself in the foot.  Or rather, it's easy for your users to shoot your server in the face.  Query_string demands proper syntax and will simply die if the users enter it incorrectly.  It also allows your users to make some horrible inefficient queries, usually through wildcards

Comment: I'm still very concerned about edge-cases here. This solution requires me to parse the input string myself, which is very non-ideal. For example, what about quotations, or other styles of negation/addition that I have not considered? Is there any way to maintain the built-in parsing from my first example while merely restricting WHICH fields are searched?

Comment: Updated my comment with an example of using the field query, which is basically a simplified query_string query.  Query_string uses the Lucene syntax you originally used, and is also the default search query when you don't specify one (which is why your original query worked).

Answer (score 0):

You want to match all the titles that have "blackberry" AND do not have have q10, not all the titles that have "blackberry" OR do not have q10.

The default boolean operator for a match is (in most cases) OR.  Try adding an "operator": "and" clause to your query instead.

Comment: Adding the "AND" operator made it so that ONLY titles with BOTH BlackBerry AND Q10 were returned. In other words, it ignored the "-" in my query string. This is confusing to me because, as I said, passing just the string into the query properly dissects the string into a FullText search ("BlackBerry -Q10" => "Has blackberry, does not have Q10"). The only difference is I want to restrict which fields are searched. Of course, I could try to parse the string myself, but I'm worried about edge cases (quotations? AND operators? etc.)

Comment: So try breaking it down into a compound query along the lines of (I'll leave it to you to convert it into lucene syntax): "title: blackberry" AND -title:q10 (in other words put the title keyword in their twice).  I'm at home in my bathrobe with a cup of coffee, so can't test this just this second but that's how I generally search for that stuff.

Comment: You're missing the point. As I said above, it is a very bad idea for me to be writing this parser myself; I am guaranteed to miss edge cases, and my function should accept freeform input from the user. ElasticSearch obviously has its own built-in parser for these FullText queries (see my first example), so why can't I leverage that?